# phpmyadmin error 502 Bad Gateway on nginex

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04, 502-error

i just installed phpmyadmin on my ubuntu 20.04 server
but when I try to go to the site I have a 502 bad gateway error ...
here is what I have in my LOG file :

```
2021/02/05 14:43:33 [crit] 662288#662288: *1 connect() to unix:/run/php/php-fpm.pid failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.127.99.149, server: databases.haristocrate.fr, request: "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php-fpm.pid:", host: "databases.haristocrate.fr"
```

I looked on a lot of site but I can not find where the problem could come from.
can someone help me please?

Comment: How about [*not* installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin)?

Comment: hum... il for my school projet so i have to do it!! haha

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `.pid` file as backend contact point.

You need to use the `.sock` socket file for it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
but i'm totally a newbie ... can you tell me how i can do this please?

Comment: You need to edit your nginx configuration files so that `fastcgi_pass` contains correct path to the PHP-FPM socket file. I cannot give any more details since they depend on the setup.

Comment: okey, i will look for it. thank you so much